# Inheriting Android Themes

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme, android-styles

I'm targeting sdk7 or Android 2.1. Here's my styles.xml that is in my values folder.

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="PrimaryText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff7c4</item>
</style>
```

And here is Android's "Theme"

```
<style name="Theme">
    <!-- Text styles -->
    <item name="textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Inverse</item>
```

**The Problem:**
Eclipse is giving me an error message of "No resource found that matches the give name: attr 'textAppearance'

This isn't true. I can see it right there in Android's theme that I'm extending. Why is there an error?

**SOLUTION:**
DOH, add the freakin' name space:

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/PrimaryText</item>
```

don't just copy and paste from Android's theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOH, add the freakin' name space:

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/PrimaryText</item>
```

don't just copy and paste from Android's theme

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project in eclipse. It might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio has a built-in Theme Editor. [See a tutorial here](http://verybadtutorials.blogspot.mx/2015/10/using-theme-editor-in-android-studio.html)